# How to create a different user type in windows form application with c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I will develop a system in C# wherein there are different types of user and these are: admin, cashier and clerk. My question is, where should I start and what are the things needed in order to do this project? Hope to have an answer with you guys! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is the privilages. 
You need to start with creating login screen upon there you should decide the **user type** that which user type is trying to logging in.

Now you have to show form to different level users.

So what I recommend is that **make separate dashboard for each role** or create a form but disable the controls that are out of privileges of some user.

But in my case first one would be preferable as it sounds more professional.!

So just start with it. If you need some more query than please do comment!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you start with a 'user' object, and inside that user object, you define a 'role' property.  Make a Global instance of the user object.  And once you have that, you can code every page/form against 'user.role' to see if it should be shown/enabled.  For logins, make a database with a users table where you store the name, password, and role....and anything else you feel like collecting about users.  Then check logins against the table.

That's about as specific as I can be given how generic this question was!